# Can't create/write to file - Error code 13 in linux

Tags: mysql, create-table, datadirectory

Iam trying to create a mysql table in linux with changing data directory to another location. The selected forlder having full permission. But I got an error 'Can't create/write to file'.
 I googled and found that this error related to permission denied. I can change the owner permission of the folder to root using *chown* command. But it still showing the same error.

```
mysql> create table test_table( testId int PRIMARY KEY,  testName VARCHAR(20) ) DATA DIRECTORY = '/home/Test/Sample/data';

ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/Test/Sample/data/test_table1.MYD' (Errcode: 13)
```

What I can do??? Please give me any valuable suggestions....

Comment: does mysql have permission to write into the `Test` user's home directory? Most likely not. Just because `data` is wide open doesn't mean `Test` or `Sample` are. MySQL has to have access rights to the ENTIRE directory tree leading up to where you want the file to go

Comment: Thanks for helping.I couldn't gave any permission to Test folder. Now its working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
mysql> create table test_table( testId int PRIMARY KEY,  testName VARCHAR(20) ) 
       DATA DIRECTORY = '/home/Test/Sample/data';
```

Write as:

```
mysql> create table test_table( testId int PRIMARY KEY,  testName VARCHAR(20) ) 
       DATA DIRECTORY = '/tmp/data';
```

To make life easier do try storing to the '/tmp' directory as mysql has access to this directory rather than fumbling around with (chown) changing ownership.

Comment: Thank you, coping with permissions are a real headache